# The code is not executed further after the connection. Disnake

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, disnake

I have such a slash command for the bot:

```
    @commands.slash_command(name='radio', description="Music", guild_ids=[])
    async def radio_voice_cmd(self, inter: disnake.CommandInteraction,
                              voice_channel: disnake.VoiceChannel = commands.Param(description="Channel")):
        await inter.response.defer()
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio('http://stream.radioparadise.com')
        voice_client = await voice_channel.connect()
        await voice_client.play(source)
        print("Connected")
        await inter.edit_original_message(content="Успешно!")
```

Connect the bot to voice channels and play music. But after `voice_client = await voice_channel.connect()` the code does not work further

Answer (score 0):

This might occur if the bot doesn't have **permission**, or a **different** type of error. You can check this article to understand how to **handle** errors: https://guide.disnake.dev/popular-topics/errors

Comment: The bot successfully connects to the voice channel, there are no errors in the console. After connecting, the code does not want to be executed further .-.

Comment: @Angeloffy discord.py by default doesn't output errors to console, they are handled using a special function. by what you said, it seems that the problem is `await voice_channel.play(source)` the FFmpegPCMAudio function isn't working properly

Comment: or again, the bot doesnt have permission to play sound